# Date value loosing the time part when called in sqlplus from linux shell script

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am using a linux shell script that queries a table through sqlplus and writes the data in a csv file and sends it in email as attachment.

I am using TO_CHAR(mydate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') which surprisingly cuts the "seconds" part from the date in the csv attachment and when I was using TO_TIMESTAMP(change_datetime, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), it cuts the whole time part and I am only able to see the date in the csv attachment.

I could see proper date value in my database table.
Please let me know in case any more information is required.

Regards,
Sachin

Comment: It would help to include your actual code. As your second statement is apparently using `to_timestamp()` I suspect your first is really using `to_date()`, and you're accidentally relying on implicit conversion and NLS settings. But was also can't see how the query results are being translated to CSV, so you could be doing something wrong in there too.

Comment: show us your code, so we can help vs guess